# Optimal tournament pool size

Tags: java, algorithm

I am stuck on a java project.I need to split the total number of players into optimal groups. I have 2 constants to help me do that (`MAX_POOL_SIZE` and `MIN_POOL_SIZE`).

For example if the total number of players is 20 the optimal group size would 4x5 and not 3x6+2(with `MAX_POOL_SIZE=6`). If i have 9 players the optimal number should be 3x3 with the same `MAX_POOL_SIZE`.

The biggest difficulty here (for me anyway) is when the total number of players is a prime number.

Comment: What is your approach for prime numbers? You can always split the groups in x*y + z where x = floor(sqrt(total number of players)), y = floor(total number of players/x) and z = total number of players - x*y.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user2302702 Please define *optimal groups*.

Comment: The optimal group size has to be decided by the program.The user only enters the total number of players.As to how the program is suppose to do that we are kinda given free choice.This is about as much detail as i was given.My question was if there was a formula/algorithm that could help me do this.

Comment: OK, but you still haven't really told us _what makes a particular group size better than another one_. Tell us that, and we may be able to help you find the best group size, whatever your definition of "best" may be.

Comment: It has to be an even number between the 2 given constants.With the constants from above(max=6,min=3) I cannot split the total number of 20 players into 2x10 or 10x2.I should however split them into 4 groups with 5 players each.

Comment: OK, but how would you, say, split 13 players when the maximum group size is 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually told us what makes a particular grouping better than another one, so your question cannot really be answered as asked.  However, based on the few examples you've given, I'm going to *guess* that you want something like the following:

- The size of each group must be between the given minimum and maximum sizes.
- Subject to the above constraint, the total number of groups must be minimized.
- If there are multiple valid ways to split the players into the same number of groups, the one with the least difference in size between the smallest and the largest group (or maybe the lowest variance of the group sizes, or something similar) is best.

Given those assumptions, here's a simple algorithm that should work:

1. Let *n* be the total number of players.
2. Let *m* be *n* divided by the maximum group size, rounded up.  We're going to divide the players into *m* groups.
3. Let *s* = *n* / *m*, rounded down.  Let *k* = *n* − *s* × *m* (or, equivalently, let *k* = *n* mod *m*).
4. Divide the players into *k* groups of *s* + 1 players and *n* − *k* groups of *s* players.

Note that I haven't explicitly taken the minimum group size into account here, but I *think* this rule will never violate it (assuming that it's *possible* not to violate it), since it, in effect, aims to maximize the size of the smallest group.

Comment: Thanks Ilmari that's what i was looking for.Sorry for the lack of details.

Comment: By the way, I just realized that my algorithm doesn't actually match your examples: for 9 players and a maximum group size of 6, it suggests dividing the players into two groups with 4 and 5 players each, rather than into three groups of 3 players each as in your example. I'll let you decide whether the error is in my algorithm or in your examples.